# How to show name of derived column not populating data in Business Object crosstab format?

Tags: business-objects

In Business object webi.

Below, for the month of Mar there is no data in derived column for A.B.C

```
Jan     Feb Apr May Jun...
```

A   1   3   3   4   5...
B   2   0   2   2   2...
C   1   3   5   1   1...

I want to have as

```
Jan     Feb Mar Apr May Jun...
```

A   1   3   0   3   4   5...
B   2   0   0   2   2   2...
C   1   3   0   5   1   1...

How it can be done, can anyone please help me out from this...

Thanks in advnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (our) current version, you can not display data that is not there.  This might not be an issue in future versions.

For date-related data, you can try to force the key periods to show up, and then LOJ your data to it.  Not the simplest as it depends upon being able to either create static tables and/or write SQL commands.

If you can get static date tables put in your database, that may be the simplest method.  A table with one entry for the first day of each month may suffice.  Adding a link from this table to your data -- using the static table as the LEFT table, will include a column with the month even for months where your data does not exist.  Finding the correct link may be a problem, tho'.

The simplest way that *I* do it is using a SQL command to feed the report, using CTEs (Common table elements), a seeded table, and date math to get a full date span for the driving table, and then date math against my real query for the join.  From there, you will have an additional (derived and driving) column to use as your new date element.

It's a pain to set up the first time, but then you have the code and can reuse it as you need.

I do something like:

```
With
MOS as (  -- CTE for # of months I plan on covering - NEGATIVELY from today's date
  Select -12 as Offset from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select -11           from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select -10           from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select  -9           from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select  -8           from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select  -7           from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select  -6           from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select  -5           from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select  -4           from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select  -3           from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select  -2           from Dual  UNION ALL
  Select  -1           from Dual  
  )
, ChartDates as (  -- gives the 1st day of the month, for the 'n' months above
  Select TRUNC( ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, MOS.offset ), 'MONTH' ) ChartMonth 
  from MOS
  )
-- Join to the real query
Select  CD.ChartMonth, YQ.*
from ChartDates CD
       Left Outer Join (YourQuery) YQ
          on CD.ChartMonth = YQ.QueryMonth
```

You will need a way to generate the equivalent "1st day of the month" from your data to use as the join condition.

From there, paste the whole thing in as the SQL and use the new field, ChartMonth, as your driving date.